# How do you edit an HTML <select> element with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, greasemonkey, html-select

There is a Pokemon battle simulator called "Pokemon Showdown".  The client is closed source so I can't add a tier to my server.  I would like to edit the final battle dropdown to add a tier.

I want to change:

```html
<select id="lobby-format" onchange="return rooms['lobby'].formSelectFormat()">
  <option value="randombattle" selected="selected">Random Battle (rated)</option>
  <option value="unratedrandombattle">Unrated Random Battle</option>
  <option value="ou">OU (rated)</option>
  <option value="cap">CAP (rated)</option>
  <option value="ubers">Ubers (rated)</option>
  <option value="uu">UU (rated)</option>
  <option value="ru">RU (rated)</option>
  <option value="nu">NU (rated)</option>
  <option value="lc">LC (rated)</option>
  <option value="hackmons">Hackmons (rated)</option>
  <option value="balancedhackmons">Balanced Hackmons (rated)</option>
  <option value="glitchmons">Glitchmons (rated)</option>
</select>
```

to:

```html
<select id="lobby-format" onchange="return rooms['lobby'].formSelectFormat()">
  <option value="randombattle" selected="selected">Random Battle (rated) </option>
  <option value="unratedrandombattle">Unrated Random Battle</option>
  <option value="ou">OU (rated)</option>
  <option value="cap">CAP (rated)</option>
  <option value="ubers">Ubers (rated)</option>
  <option value="uu">UU (rated)</option>
  <option value="ru">RU (rated)</option>
  <option value="nu">NU (rated)</option>
  <option value="pu">PU (unrated)</option>
  <option value="lc">LC (rated)</option>
  <option value="bwcup">BW Cup (unrated)</option>
  <option value="hackmons">Hackmons (rated)</option>
  <option value="balancedhackmons">Balanced Hackmons (rated)</option>
  <option value="glitchmons">Glitchmons (rated)</option>
</select>
```

(Inserting 2 `<options>` at select locations.)

Comment: Well not much really, my javascript sorta fails.

Comment: I just google for "change html select elements with greasemonkey"

Comment: If anyone with at least some brain cells wrote that server software, the modification of that request will have no effect at all, as the parameters will be checked for valid input, which yours is not, I guess. Don't waste your time on that.

Comment: Actually, I'm hosting the server.  I can add a tier, I just can't search it because I can't edit the client

Answer (score 2):

Ok, try that:

```
var opt = document.createElement("option");

var content = document.createTextNode("PU (unrated)");
opt.appendChild(content);

var attr = document.createAttribute("value");
attr.nodeValue = "pu";
opt.setAttributeNode(attr);

var targetEl = document.getElementById("lobby-format");
targetEl.appendChild(opt);
```

This will add just one more option, but I guess you get the point.

Comment: it didn't do anything.  is there a way to just edit edit This chunk of html to, that chunk of html?

Comment: this is the page I want to add it to btw http://play.pokemonshowdown.com/~~fearon-ps.herokuapp.com:80/lobby

Comment: Yeah, because that whole thing uses ajax. Take Firefox or Chrome, open the page, wait until the dropdown appears, paste that code into the js console, hit enter. The option will be added, but after selecting it, there is a whole lot of Javascript executed producing several errors. You can not hack into this by just adding this option, sorry...

Comment: BTW: There is a big fat "report bug" link at the top right. Why don't you use this if that is a missing feature?

Comment: js console?  sorry for my noobiness

Comment: And, it's not really a missing feature.  Just the client source hasn't been released yet so I can't add a tier to it.

Comment: In Safari and Chrome, there is an included JS console, in Firefox you may need to activate it in the tools menu. Just google it...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that adds options, at targeted points, using the awesome power of jQuery (tested [at jsBin](http://jsbin.com/azeveh)):

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Add new options at select points
// @include  http://play.pokemonshowdown.com/*
// @include  http://jsbin.com/azeveh*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var selectNode  = $("#lobby-format");

selectNode  .find ("option[value='nu']")
            .after ('<option value="pu">PU (unrated)</option>');

selectNode  .find ("option[value='lc']")
            .after ('<option value="bwcup">BW Cup (unrated)</option>');
```

---

---

The OP's particular site uses AJAX to add that `<select>`.   To compensate for AJAX, use the `waitForKeyElements` utility. Like so:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Add new options at select points, AJAX compensated.
// @include     http://jsbin.com/azeveh*
// @include     http://play.pokemonshowdown.com/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// ==/UserScript==

waitForKeyElements ("#lobby-format option[value='nu']", AddOption_1);
waitForKeyElements ("#lobby-format option[value='lc']", AddOption_2);

function AddOption_1 (jNode) {
    jNode.after ('<option value="pu">PU (unrated)</option>');
}

function AddOption_2 (jNode) {
    jNode.after ('<option value="bwcup">BW Cup (unrated)</option>');
}
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't work.  I'll try restarting firefox, anything else i'd need to do?

Comment: If it stopped working, your page changed away from what was specified in the question.  Does the URL still match the `@include` directive(s)?  `https`?  Does the select still have that id and those options?

Comment: The code works perfectly, as intended.  But that site uses (slow) AJAX.  Compensating for AJAX is a whole new problem, but see the updated answer.  (PS:  Always state if the page is using AJAX for the code of interest!)