# Changing dropdown options in a website with Firefox and Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

I want to change the options in a dropdown menu in a website I use, so as to increase the number of rows it displays in a table.  Since I use Firefox, my thought was to use GreaseMonkey, but I'm having trouble since most resources on this were written before the [backward-compatibility breaking](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/04/10/changes-to-unsafewindow-for-the-add-on-sdk/) [GM 2.0 update](http://www.greasespot.net/2014/06/greasemonkey-20-release.html), [because jQuery is involved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146445/jquery-in-greasemonkey-1-0-conflicts-with-websites-using-jquery), and also because my JS knowledge fits comfortably on the head of a pin.

[Here's the full HTML code](http://pastebin.com/ew4WMGRp) but the relevant excerpts are below.  The dropdown code:

```
<select onchange="set_pagination(this.value)">

    <option value="10"></option>
    <option value="20"></option>
    <option value="30"></option>
    <option value="40"></option>
    <option value="50" selected="selected"></option>

</select>
```

And here's the set_pagination function:

```
function set_pagination(val) {
        jQuery('#my_word_bank_div').fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
        jQuery.post("/learningcenter/account/set_pagination", {number_of_rows_perpage: val}, function(data){
            if(data.error == "") reload_table(1);
            else alert(data.error);
        }, "json");
    }
```

My naive solution of redefining the function but setting `val` to a constant (e.g. 200) didn't work, probably due to my misuse of `unsafeWindow`.  I did find [this similar request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471601/auto-select-items-per-page-a-drop-down-using-a-greasemonkey-like-script) but I'm not sure it applies anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found my answer, sort of.  Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873505/how-do-you-edit-an-html-select-element-with-greasemonkey) for guidance, and learning some basics about [using jQuery to access elements without an id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236624/how-to-access-html-element-without-id), and also [by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732364/how-to-find-elements-with-value-x), I came up with the following simple Greasemonky script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        ZZZZ
// @namespace   http://www.example.com*
// @description Add dropdown option
// @include     http://www.example.com*
// @version     1
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_getResourceText
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @grant       GM_getResourceUR
// ==/UserScript==

var rowDropdownAddOption = $('[value=50]').after ('<option value="51">Show 51</option>');
```

This successfully adds the dropdown option I'm after, but (SPOILER ALERT), of course the server must check the parameters, and anything >50 is rejected.  Which, of course, just goes to show my naivete in all matters web.  I think this means it can't be done, unless someone can offer up some other solution.

Comment: Don't use jQuery for something like this. jQuery is 82kiB of minimized code which you're loading in order to save a few characters of vanilla JavaScript. That's not a good trade-off for your users. What if they have hundreds of tabs open to that page? What you're doing could easily be done as `document.querySelector('[value=50]').insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<option value="51">Show 51</option>');`

Comment: How are we supposed to "offer up some other solution" when you haven't described what you *actually* want to do. You've said you want another option added to a `<select>`. This code does that. You haven't provided remotely enough information for us to be able to provide solutions to your *actual* problem. Basically what your question is, is a [XY problem](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=XY+problem). That's not actually a bad thing from the point of view of this question. The question's relatively contained, has an answer. OTOH, it is a bad thing because your actual problem isn't solved.